# Derived category of coherent sheaves with a codimension $\geq$ 1 support

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be some smooth algebraic variety. I would like to understand the relation between the following two categories:

1. $D^b_{cd,1}\text{Coh}(X) \subset D^b\text{Coh}(X)$: the full subcategory of the derived category of coherent sheaves with cohomologies being supported in codimension $\geq 1$.
2. $D^b\text{Coh}_{cd,1}(X)$: The derived category of the abelian category of coherent sheaves supported in codimension $\geq 1$.

I was trying to show that for a bounded complex $F^\bullet$ of coherent sheaves with cohomologies supported in codimension $\geq 1$ there exists a quasi-isomorphic complex $E^\bullet$ with $E^i$ being supported in codimension $\geq 1$, which would show that they are equivalent, but I have ran into some problems like $i_*\circ i^*$ for $i$ a closed immersion not being exact (the idea was to take the union of the support of cohomologies and restrict the complex to this union). Is it still true that these categories are equivalent? If not, are they at least related in some nice way?

**Edit:** For now, I can only say that the natural t-structures on both of these triangulated categories give the same hearts, but I would need more than that to show equivalence.

Comment: Isn't this just checkable at the generic points? Taking stalks is exact so I don't think there is a problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that I can construct a quasi-isomorphic complex by taking stalks at the generic points?

Comment: What I'm saying is that being supported in codimension >=1 for coherent sheaf is the same as having zero stalk for each generic point, and taking stalk at a generic point is exact so it is actually a functor of derived categories. Say there is one generic point $i:\eta\rightarrow X$ then $Li^{*}=i^{*}:D^{b}Coh(X)\rightarrow D^{b}Coh(\eta)$ and both conditions are equivalent to complexes mapped to zero complex via $i^{*}$ because a complex with zero cohomology is quasi-isomorphic to zero complex.

Comment: I think one can construct the complex by taking a large enough subscheme of codimension $\ge 1$, for example the subscheme given by $\ker(\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{End}(\mathcal{H}^*F))$. Then $\mathcal{H}^*F$ will be acyclic with respect to the pullback onto this subscheme

Comment: However, even if we are able to construct such a complex, it doesn't mean that the hom must be the same in both categories.

Comment: @GTA I see that the condition for the complex restricted to a generic point being acyclic is equivalent to it lying in 1., but it seems that it only restates the question about why this should be equivalent to it being in 2.

Comment: @WilleLiou I think once one shows that there is a quasi-isomorphic complex of that form, then by looking at the morphisms in terms of roofs, it should follow that the Homs are the same.

Comment: @GTA yes, that is how I can see why it is true for 1., but why should a complex with vanishing cohomologies at the generic point be quasi-isomorphic to one with each term being trivial at the generic point?

Comment: @Arkadij Bojko But one category contains more objects which are quasi-isomorphic to the given complex than the other. Remember that the definition of hom in the derived category takes all roofs.

Comment: @WilleLiou Huybrecht in his proof of Proposition 3.5 in Fourier–Mukai transforms in
algebraic geometry is satisfied with showing the existence of a quasi-isomorphic complex of the abelian subcategory, so I think it should still work. I think one can use the composition rule for the roofs to replace the objects at the top of the roof.

Comment: @Arkadij Bojko Sorry, I realized I misunderstood your point before you replied.

Comment: Maybe I am pointing out the obvious, but note that the coh. sheaves supported in codim $\geq1$ form a Serre subcategory (even better, torsion class) in the category of coh. sheaves. The question in this setting is somewhat considered in stacks project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06UP but the criterion for equivalence there does not seem to fit this setting.